# Static methods save memory? (unmanaged code)

Tags: c++, memory, static, unmanaged

In the wake of [this question about static methods in managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496629/do-static-members-help-memory-efficiency), I'm interesting if the answers there is relevant to unmanaged code like c++.

I make thousands of instances, and my question is mainly about static methods. Do this methods save memory compared regular methods?

thank you, and sorry about my poor English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All methods require their binary code to be in memory in order to run. The executable code for `static` and `non-static` methods is (largely) the same.

Both types of methods require only one place in memory, so they're not replicated with every instance of the class.

Let's now take a look at some code:

```
class A
{
public:
   void foo();
   static void goo();
};

void A::foo()
{
004113D0  push        ebp  
004113D1  mov         ebp,esp 
004113D3  sub         esp,0CCh 
004113D9  push        ebx  
004113DA  push        esi  
004113DB  push        edi  
004113DC  push        ecx  
004113DD  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh] 
004113E3  mov         ecx,33h 
004113E8  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
004113ED  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 
004113EF  pop         ecx  
004113F0  mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],ecx 
}
004113F3  pop         edi  
004113F4  pop         esi  
004113F5  pop         ebx  
004113F6  mov         esp,ebp 
004113F8  pop         ebp  
004113F9  ret     


void A::goo()
{
00411530  push        ebp  
00411531  mov         ebp,esp 
00411533  sub         esp,0C0h 
00411539  push        ebx  
0041153A  push        esi  
0041153B  push        edi  
0041153C  lea         edi,[ebp-0C0h] 
00411542  mov         ecx,30h 
00411547  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
0041154C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 
}
0041154E  pop         edi  
0041154F  pop         esi  
00411550  pop         ebx  
00411551  mov         esp,ebp 
00411553  pop         ebp  
00411554  ret           



int main()
{
   A a;
   a.foo();
0041141E  lea         ecx,[a] 
00411421  call        foo (4111E5h) 
   a.goo();
00411426  call        A::goo (4111EAh) 
   return 0;
}
```

There are only minor differences, such as pushing the `this` pointer onto the stack for the non-static function, but they are minor, and probably a decent optimizer will reduce the differences even further.

A decision about whether or not to use static functions should be strictly design-driven, not memory-driven.

Comment: Can you explain, please, what we saw in your example? Thank you

Comment: @yoni this is the machine code. C++ code is compiled to this, these are the actual instructions that run on your processor.

Comment: thank you but I already knew that. My question was where, in your example, we saw proof of your claims?

Answer (score 4):

Static methods are essentially just free functions and so their memory footprint is the same. Member functions  have an extra parameter and so the added memory is slightly larger, although it's meaningless to care about such things.

The amount of memory a function takes up is per-class, not per-instance. You shouldn't be concerned.

Comment: I find the "extra parameter so added memory" a bit confusing. It is a per-call cost that is rescinded when the call ends, and not a per-function cost as I read from your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No. A method is a function with an implicit first argument equal to its class, and a static function lacks this first argument. Actually, the situation is just the same as in garbage collected languages, so the answers to the other question apply fully.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a static and instance method is just the first parameter. In C++ all instance methods compile to a normal function with a substituted first parameter called *this* which is a pointer to the object on which the method was called.

On most architectures this will be an 8-byte value, so it's not really significant unless you're doing some very resource-strict embedded systems coding.