# Do Java static properties affect performance?

Tags: java, optimization, import, static

My question is whether or not making multiple instances of an object that has static members affects performance.  Is there new memory allocated for each of the static variables every time you instantiate the class?

Also, I'd like to know what kind of affect importing a class has on performance in general.  For example, is it a bad idea to import an entire class just to reference one of its variables?  Or does it not matter?

I'm working on a game so that's why I'm worrying about optimization

Comment: `import` statements do not have any impact on the performance of your program at all. They are a compile-time only thing; your bytecode isn't going to be different if you import a class or if you use it with its fully-qualified class name.

Comment: Make your program work correctly.  Then look at performance.  Lots of problems are caused by `premature optimization`.

Answer (score 1):

Static fields belong to the class, and not to instances of the class. So creating an instance doesn't allocate anything for static members. They simply keep their current value.

Imports don't exist at runtime. They're only used to allow you writing List instead of java.util.List in your source code. If you only used qualified class names and removed all the imports, the bytecode generated by the compiler would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, static members save memory because there's just a single copy of the data per class [Static members memory efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496629/do-static-members-help-memory-efficiency).

Also using the import-statement does not really import a class. It only give you a shortcut to access the class. When importing the class you don't have to write the fully qualified name of a class with all it's package names. So for example instead of writing `java.util.List` every you can just write `List` after importing the class by `import java.util.List;`.