# Why is passwordEncoder() as a @Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop, spring-security

Why is passwordEncoder() defined as @Bean if its called directly as a function? Here's the example I'm talking about

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(accountDto.getPassword()));
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt

Or I've seen people do it on 
 `auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());`

Comment: I am not getting your question fully, do you mean to ask if we can use the `PasswordEncoder` just by calling the method, then why we need to define it as bean.

Comment: Yes, I dont understand why @Bean annotation is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Bean` annotation can appear over method, this is one possibility to register beans. This way `BeanFactory` is aware of this bean and qualifies it with name derived from method name (`"passwordEncoder"`). Other way would be to name them explicitly:

```
 @Bean({"b1", "b2"}) // bean available as 'b1' and 'b2', but not 'myBean'
 public MyBean myBean() {
     // instantiate and configure MyBean obj
     return obj;
 }
```

Consult the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) for more info.

Edit: in the example `@Bean` is defined to bind the abstraction `PasswordEncoder` to the implementation `BCryptPasswordEncoder`. Otherwise spring would not know, what's the concrete class if there were more of them in scan.

Comment: What do you mean by "to bind the abstraction PasswordEncoder to the implementation BCryptPasswordEncoder" ?

Comment: `BCryptPasswordEncoder` implements `PasswordEncoder`, but there could be another class, that does that, say `Banana` - without this definition, how would spring know what to take - `BCryptPasswordEncoder` or `Banana` if you write `@Autowired PasswordEncoder`?

Comment: I didn't write @Autowired PasswordEncoder, isn't passwordEncoder() just a simple function call which returns a new object of type BCryptPasswordEncoder which implements PasswordEncoder?

Comment: You can use it this way, you can also autowire. You do know about dependency injection? If you call it as a method, then you don't need it.

Comment: Oh yeah I see now that it is @Autowired in that example, my bad. what threw me off are these tutorials were there password encoder isnt injected its just called as a method https://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-boot-spring-mvc-role-based-spring-security-jpa-thymeleaf-mysql-tutorial.html https://www.javainuse.com/spring/boot_security_jdbc_authentication_bcrypt

Answer (score 2):

You need to read more about [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), DI is a pattern which solves many of the problems, especially when used with [Program to Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697783/what-does-program-to-interfaces-not-implementations-mean) , in this case if you don't write `@Bean` it would force it to create multiple instances of the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` every time you call the method. While if you write `@Bean` the instantiation and management of bean's life cycle is managed by the `Spring Container`, which again ensures that only single instance is created due to `Singleton` scope being the default one in spring. Read more on [singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319434/singleton-pattern) here.

Answer (score 0):

@Bean annotation is used to register any object/method to the Spring container as Bean.

In your problem to use the passwordEncoder() method as a bean, it is marked with @Bean annotation so that it can be easily injected to other Objects and used.

Comment: I dont see were it is injected, its just called as a method