# Singleton Design Pattern Implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I saw a different variety of implementations of Singleton Class. However, this particular implementation : https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/java/1
does not create the object in a private constructor.

Can someone explain, what the advantages or disadvantages between the two implementations would be ? The description given is minimal and I have not understood much from it.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between singleton class and static class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714971/difference-between-singleton-class-and-static-class)

Comment: Take a look at:  http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2013/03/difference-between-singleton-pattern-vs-static-class-java.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided explains it very well, if succinctly... but let me try to expand...

> The inner class is referenced no earlier (and therefore loaded no earlier by the class loader) than the moment that getInstance() is called.

This is the most important part of the explanation.

The inner class the above text is referring to is the `SingletonHolder` class, which exists solely for the purpose of holding an instance of `Singleton`.

Because this class is private and not referred to anywhere else, it is guaranteed that this class will not be initialized (loaded by the Java ClassLoader) until the `getInstance()` method of `Singleton` is called, because that's the earliest a JVM is required to initialize that class.

When a class is initialized, any static final fields (and static blocks) it contains are initialized before the class is made available to any user code. This initialization is thread-safe, so the code using this pattern does not need any of the complicated synchronization logic you will typically find in other implementations of the singleton pattern in Java.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java?rq=1) for more discussions about alternative implementations, including the `enum` based solution as well as the more complicated, explicitly synchronized versions of Singleton.

Notice that if you don't care about making your singleton lazy-loaded (ie. only initialized when needed), then just use the simplest possible way:

```
class Singleton {
    public static final INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    private Singleton() { /* cannot be instantiated externally */ }
}
```