# Calling a public method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, public-method

I'm trying to figure out how to centralize a method that I use in a few of my ViewControllers.  I already had a singleton that I was using for some variables.  I called the singleton class Shared.

I moved my method to the Shared class and tried calling it like so:

```
m.createdAt = [Shared getUTCFormateDate:[messageObject objectForKey:@"created_at"]];
```

It's giving me an exception saying that the selector doesn't exist when it tries to call it.

I have already imported Shared.h.  Any other thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to use a Singleton, basically the only way to do it is like in every other iOS app -- simply use Matt Gallagher's famous singleton macro file: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html  Link to the actual file: http://projectswithlove.com/projects/SynthesizeSingleton.h.zip   Many problems in programming ARE SOLVED: this is one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class is named "Shared" then it looks like you are trying to call a class method rather than an instance method. So, you need to declare the method with + instead of -.

Comment: I thought I had the plus sign but you were right.  That was it!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct pattern for creating a Singleton in objective-c: (Ill use an example of a User object.. taken from code I have open in front of me).  also, please note that there is a difference between Singleton classes and Static Class methods, as discussed here.. [Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

in the .h file, declare a static method that returns an *instance* of your class.

```
+(User *) currentUser;
```

in the .m file, create a static variable that holds your instance

```
static User * _user;
```

then, in your .m class, create your "public" static accesor GET that returns or instantiates and returns your  static variable

```
+ (User *) currentUser
    {

        if (!_user) 
        {
            _user =[[User alloc]init];
            // ... init the singleton user properties and what not
            // ...
        }

        return _user;   

    }
```

then, when you want to call on your Singleton class you just make sure that User.h is imported and call `[[User currentUser] someMethodorProperty]`;

enjoy

Comment: Thanks.  I already had a working Singleton though that I've been using with shared variables.  This is where I'm trying to call a Shared method.  I had forgotten the + sign.