# Call or Instantiate?

Tags: php, class, methods

I building a website in php where I'll have to make User, Case & Task classes, each of which going to have couple of methods. In my index.php I'll need to do some CRUD operation that I've wrote in my classes. So which is better to call a method and send parameters to like `Case::update(2)` or its better to instantiate the class first then call a method like

```
$case = new Case();
$case->update(2);
```

Comment: This highly (and only) depends on the architecture you have chosen.

Comment: Would you mind to explain more please?

Comment: Ans: Consider this: Can you rephrase your question so that it can be answered objectively?

Comment: Don't use static classes/calls for such things -- it's MUCH MORE difficult to debug and extend such code. Definitely go "instantiate" way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as KingCrunch already mentioned in the comments, it totally depends on your whole architecture. Furthermore, it also depends on your preferences. If you read through the following links you may have a better overview and can choose for yourself:

- [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)
- [PHP Patterns](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.patterns.php)
- [Static versus non Static in PHP](http://harx.nl/component/content/article/1-php/39-static-versus-non-static-in-php)
- [The Singleton Design Pattern for PHP](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/php-singleton-design-pattern-050729-1050/)
- [Static call versus Singleton call in PHP](http://moisadoru.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/static-call-versus-singleton-call-in-php/)
- [Why Singletons have no use in PHP](http://gooh.posterous.com/singletons-in-php)
- [Difference between static class and singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

Comment: Good resources, thank you very much.