# Using object of another class without passing it to a constructor

Tags: java, oop

I am working on GUI app (simple game), where one of the objects (Let us call it Object A) uses images that I load directly. I am implementing method loading images on game start so that I do not have to reload files every time I reconfigure the game etc. That method loads all necessary images as an array, then another method (`BufferedImage[] getImages()`); returns this array. The class of which this method is (Object B, a JPanel), draws Object A, which in turn, was instantiated by Object C (JFrame, which, of course, also instantiates object B).

I want to know if I can access Object B’s `getImages()` method directly from the Object A’s method without passing a reference via method call. Is it entirely possible (via ClassPath etc.), and would it be good programming practise to do so?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a singleton pattern. Do this:

```
public class ImageContainer {
    private final BufferedImage[] images = null;

    private static ImageContainer _instance = new ImageContainer();

    // NOTE PRIVATE CONSTRUCTOR
    private ImageContainer() {
        BufferedImage[] images = loadImages();
    }

    public static ImageContainer getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }

    private BufferedImage[] loadImages() {
        // Do the loading image logic
    }

    // You might not want this in favor of the next method, so clients don't have direct access to your array
    public BufferedImage[] getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage(int index) {
        return BufferedImage[i];
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need an image, just do

```
ImageContainer.getInstance().getImage(3);
```

You could even use an `EnumMap` instead of an array to make it easier to know what image to return in your code.

---

By the way, you can read an excellent discussion on [the different reasons when you would and would not use a static method here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

Comment: @theUg: Dependency injection is wonderful when you need it (potential change of a data source, for example)... And it's good to build early in a project's lifestyle because it's really tough to refactor in... But totally unnecessary for a homework assignment :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call B's getImages() method without having a reference only if getImages is a static method. This may or may not be a good idea, depending on your situation.

Another option is to make B a "singleton" class.
You can do that approximately like this:

```
public class B {
  private static B theInstance;
  private bufferedImage[] images;
  private B() {
  }

  public static B getInstance() {
    if(theInstance == null) {
      theInstance = new B();
    }
    return theInstance;
  }

  public BufferedImage[] getImages() {
       if(images == null) {
            /* get the images */
       }
       return images;
  }
}
```

Note, however, that singletons are frowned upon by some folks. 
The alternative is [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: So, would the static method do the same thing as singleton class (for the purposes of my application) as it produces single object as well? What would be a better way, given the singleton concerns, or your warning about how static method may or may not be a good idea?

Comment: @theUg: I edited a good link about static vs singleton into my answer above

Comment: @durron597 - that's what well-known patterns and idioms are all about - it makes it easier for us to read and understand each other's code :-)

Comment: @theUg - I personally think that many of these discussions are nit-picking, and a single static method vs. a singleton is largely a matter of style. The big win is with dependency injection, which provides the means to easily unit test other components that would otherwise be tightly coupled to the singleton - the test class can inject a mock into the class under test (instead of the 'real' class).

Comment: @durron597 And what about my other option (passing reference to the result of those methods in a constructor of methods of Object A)? How does that compares to another two from the standpoint of OOP, and other considerations (maintenance, refactoring etc.). Again, I am not going to lose sleep over it (school project), but for the sake of learning?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Why are singleton classes frowned upon?

Comment: @pratnala Mostly because of over-use of the pattern. They can also be a bit inflexible. But they are still useful in some situations.