# what examples of static classes vs. singleton

Tags: static, singleton

I read the answer about static vs singelton, however, i specifically look for concrete examples of when should i use a static class instead of a singelton. As it seems at the moment, singelton should always be used.

Thanks.

Comment: The singleton is a pattern. A pattern is supposed to be a solution for a problem you might experience.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the book "Design patterns - Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" by Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson and John Vlissides (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

Among the differences, a singleton can be be lazily constructed, requiring no memory or resources until needed.

Comment: But a static need not be constructed at all.

Comment: @weston it does. There are static constructors for example.

Comment: @Aphelion Sure, but 1. they don't construct anything unless you call `new` statements inside them and 2. they are lazy (c# at least), being called on the first time the class is used, which is precisely their argument for using singleton over static.