# Differences between static constructor and defind static instance in global class

Tags: c#, .net, static, global, static-constructor

What is differences between static constructor as the following:

```
class GlobalClass
{

    public static DataBase dataBase;

    static GlobalClass()
    {
        dataBase= new DataBase(@"Data Source=..;...; User ID=... ;Password=...;");
        dataBase.CreateConnection();
    }
}
```

And defined static instance in global class as the following:

```
class GlobalClass
{

    public static GlobalClass Globals = new GlobalClass();

    public DataBase dataBase;

    public  GlobalClass()
    {
        dataBase= new DataBase(@"Data Source=..;...; User ID=... ;Password=...;");
        dataBase.CreateConnection();
    }
}
```

What is differences between each type? And which is better to use?

Comment: Did you really mean to ask about the difference between initialising a static field inline at the point of declaration, and initialising a static field inside a static constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first case database initialized only **once**, when `GlobalClass` accessed first time.

In second case database initialized **each time** when you create `GlobalClass` instance. No instances - no initializations. Two instances - two initializations (only last one will be available via `dataBase` field).

Comment: even in the second case, I can to access database and it will initialize without create instances of the GlopalClass... So, I don't find any difference between two cases.

Comment: @werwerwer I see, that is because of static field `public static GlobalClass Globals = new GlobalClass();` which creates new instance of class, but each time you create new instance of `GlobalClass` you will initialize database again

Comment: mmmmm, And in the first case by default I can't create instance form 'GlobalClass()', So I will initialize database one times only. that's right??

Comment: @werwerwer yes, exactly - in first case you will have only one instance of database, which will be initialized before first usage of `GlobalClass`

Comment: Okay,Thanks ^^
the last thing, If you have any idea to What's the best using for each case? tell me about it ..

Comment: @FreeUser that depends on what you want. If you want to be sure database is initialized once, then go with [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or static constructor. If you need different DataBase instance for each `GlobalClass` (which seems weird for me, because you usually don't have several global classes) then initialize database in instance constructor (or use dependency injection to provide database instance).

Answer (score 1):

While initially similar in function they are not the same.

The second version is an implementation of the Singleton pattern, is the more flexible of the two.

The biggest advantage is since `Globals` is assignable, it can be reassigned.  One use is where you have multiple subtypes of the `GlobalClass`, you can assign an instance of the appropriate subtype for the given context.

You can read more about Singleton versus static here: [Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)