# Java: when would I ever want to use static methods when I can use a singleton instead?

Tags: java, class, oop, static, singleton

Having read [Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern), none of the answers list any advantages for using a static method over a singleton, which leads me to wonder why anyone would ever want to use static methods.

Comment: I am asking for advantages of using static methods in case that wasn't clear...

Comment: Motorbike is not called anti-vehicle, while singleton is largely marked with anti-pattern, even thought it might seem to help.

Comment: @JasonC that was so ironic, I just had to vote like that as well...

Comment: @JasonC answering and duplicate marking??

Comment: @NarendraPathai Yes. Any other questions? :)

Comment: @JasonC I will post them as a separate post for you to answer!

Comment: It would be foolish to create a singleton purely to allow one to call what is essentially a static method.  Understand the difference between static methods and static data.

Comment: Hint:  Look at class java.lang.Math, and explain how using a singleton to address one of those methods would do anything other than add overhead and complexity.

Answer (score 5):

As with all questions of this nature, use the right tool for the job. Use a singleton when your class represents an object that there can be only one of. Use static methods when your methods are appropriate for the class they are members of but do not rely on a specific instance of that class.

In general, use your best judgment. Go for clean, precise, maintainable code, keeping the overall big picture in mind.

Comment: One important specific case: a singleton class often has a static getInstance method to give users access to the singleton.

Comment: Down voter please add something constructive. Additional opinions are valuable here. :)