# Should i use thread safe or non thread safe for my Singleton class for my purpose?

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to implement `Singleton` and found this acrticle from `MSDN` with several examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

I have application that host `WCF` service.
the application get `String` from `Client`, and sent this string to my `Singleton`.
And from `Singleton class` i am open my `Job` class that do my stuff (open process..).
The job class contain `Event` that each time process started to ends update my UI.
and `Singleton class` should subscribe to this event.
Also i am open new `Singleton` instance when my application start.

My service `ServiceBehavior` defined as `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` and `InstanceContextMode.PerSession` so every client message create new instance:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
```

so my only qustion is shold i use thread safe or non thread safe in my `Singleton class` ?

Comment: why not to use a thread safe?

Comment: The question is not why not but if i need it or not

Comment: Make it thread safe, there are no drawbacks in make it thread safe and you can avoid future headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/519530/569662), [a singleton should be thread safe.](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

Comment: So Multithreaded Singleton from the above link with my event will do the job ?

Comment: @hugh take a look at [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx).

Comment: What version should i use ?

Comment: What version of what now?

Comment: what version, i can see six verions

Comment: Version 4 looks nice. I would use that.

Answer (score 1):

You should always opt for the thread-safe version when you are building something that can be **modified**. If it is a read-only collection then thread safety is not important.

Thread safety will incur a small performance cost usually due to locking, but it will save you a lot of potential pain later as race conditions are usually hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Thread unsafe may end up with weird results, possible to create more than 1 instance, which violates the singleton pattern. Thread Safe singleton is a good way to go.

Take a look to Jon Skeet's article, with different approach like Thread Safety, lazy instantiation etc.

http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx