# Java best practice: Class with only static methods

Tags: java, static, singleton, nio

I have an application where I have a class called `PlausibilityChecker`. This class has only static methods, like `checkZipcodeFormat` or `checkMailFormat`. I use them in my GUI classes to check the input before sending it to the lower layer.

Is this good practice? I thought I'd go with only static methods so that I don't have to care about passing an instance to the GUI classes or having an instance field in each gui class that doesn't reference a gui object.

I noticed that the `Files` class of `Java NIO` has only static methods so I assume this can't be that horribly wrong.

Comment: As long as it has no state, you're fine.

Comment: Static classes are OK, just don't forget to add a private constructor. Ah, and mind multi-threading accesses.

Comment: Provide more information about the structure of your program.

Comment: We usually name such classes as *Helper, There's nothing wrong in having those. Extra `private constuctor()` can prevent from instantiation,

Comment: I've also often seen it named "Utility"

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern .

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I would say you're doing it right. Apart of that, some advices for your utility class:

- Make sure it doesn't have any state. This is, there's no field in the class unless it's declared `static final`. Also, make sure this field is immutable as well e.g. `String`s.
- Make sure it cannot be a super class of other classes. Make the class `final` so other programmers cannot extend it.
- This one is debatable, but you may declare a no-arg constructor `private`, so no other class could create an instance of your utility class (using reflection or something similar will do, but there's no need to go that protective with the class). Why you may not do this? Well, this is the strange case where you want/need to inject an instance of the utility class e.g. through an interface rather than directly using it along your class. [Here's an example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31411587/1065197). This design is really odd but may happen (as shown in the link above), but if you will not run in such case, the best advice is to keep the constructor `private`.

There are lot of libraries that provide utility classes in order to help us programmers with our work. One of the most known is [Apache Common](https://commons.apache.org/) set of libraries. It's open source and you can check the code to see how they design these utility classes in order to create yours. (DISCLAIMER: I do not work or support these libraries, I'm a happy user of them)

Important Note: [**Avoid using a singleton for your utility class**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

Comment: wouldn't it be better if he uses singleton pattern and create all the functions normally except for `getInstance()` ?

Comment: @BugsHappen [don't use singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons), [it's evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil).

Comment: for the 1st bullet point, i think it's not quite enough to say make sure any fields are static final since a final field can reference something mutable; i'd say make sure there's nothing mutable and that there are no dependencies on anything external (filesystem, database, etc.). although the nio Files example goes against that last part.

Answer (score 29):

In Java 8 you can now change your static utility classes to interfaces with static implementations.  This eliminates the need for making the class final and having to provide a private constructor.  It's as simple as changing 'class' to 'interface' and removing the final word if you have it (all interfaces are abstract so they cannot be final).  Since interface methods are always public you can remove any public scope from them.  If you have a private constructor then remove that as well (you can't compile an interface with a constructor since they can't be instantiated).  It's less code and looks cleaner.  You won't have to refactor any classes that already use it.

Comment: Extension methods are not supported at language level '7'.
Static interface method requires API level 24

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry about subclassing or instantiation. The following utility classes in JDK can be subclassed or instantiated, yet nobody has misused them in all those years. People are not *that* stupid.

```
java.beans.Beans
java.beans.PropertyEditorManager
java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory
java.lang.reflect.Modifier
java.net.URLDecoder                                   ...but not URLEncoder:)
javax.management.DefaultLoaderRepository
javax.management.Query
javax.management.loading.DefaultLoaderRepository
javax.management.relation.RoleStatus
javax.print.ServiceUI
javax.swing.UIManager
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicBorders
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicGraphicsUtils
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicHTML
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicIconFactory
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalIconFactory
javax.swing.text.Utilities
javax.swing.text.html.HTML
```

However, as a public API, you do want to suppress the default constructor, otherwise there is an undocumented constructor on the javadoc page which is awkward and confusing. For your own in-house APIs, it doesn't matter, nobody cares.

There is no reason to suppress subclassing though. If anyone wants to subclass a utility class, for whatever reason, let him. Of course, private constructor will suppress subclassing as a side effect.

---

In java8, there are more design possibilities to consider -

*An interface with all static methods* - this is just as good as a class with all static methods. Neither interface nor class is designed for this purpose, so either one is OK. However, don't expect to inherit these static methods in subtypes of the interface - interface static methods are not inheritable. One plus point for using interface is that we don't need to suppress the default constructor from appearing on javadoc.

*An interface with all default methods* - accessed through inheritance. This is interesting but problematic in general (the inheritance works only in non-static context). But it might be a better option in some API designs, for example, this [html builder](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/html/Custom_Builder.html#Builder_Interface) API.

Comment: This goes against Joshua Bloch's advice in his Effective Java book where he advises you to only use interfaces to define types.

Answer (score 2):

Classes with only static methods is a common pattern in Java for utility methods. Examples in the standard library include [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), and [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

For such utility classes, it's a good idea to make sure that your class cannot be instantiated, to make the intent of the class clear. You can do so by explicitly declaring a private constructor. See [Item 4: Enforce noninstantiability with a private constructor](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=4) in "Effective Java" by Josh Bloch for details.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it not be good practice if you just have methods which provides "tools" to other classes this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Singleton are ok, depending on the context.

For testing purposes, you may want to mock out references to singletons to avoid side effects during unit tests. 
In that case, it probably makes sense to use a dependency injection framework such as Spring to handle the creation of the instance and use regular methods  which can be overridden instead of static methods.

If you still plan to use static methods, ensure that the calls are thread-safe if used in a multi-threaded context. (e.g. double-checked locking).

Comment: Static methods != singleton. For utility classes with only static methods, there is often no instance of the class at all.