# How to annotate helper class to be visible inside JSF?

Tags: jsf, annotations

I have a helper class, which is neither a `stateful` `managed bean`, nor a `stateless` `EJB`, nor an `entity` mapped to a table via `JPA` or `Hibernate`.  It is simply a collection of static methods that do simple things like return date formats and similar.

Given that, in order for a Java class to be visible inside a JSF, that class must be annotated in a way that the container assigns as visible to JSFs, is there a way to annotate a helper class that does not match any of the standard JSF visible categories so that it becomes visible?  An alternative, of course, is to have a conduit method in the managed bean that passes the call from the JSF to the helper class but I prefer not to clutter my managed bean if I can call it directly from the JSF.  I understand that doing this with a stateless EJB from a JSF would be considered an anti-pattern but the methods in the class I wish to use are all very simple and non-transactional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark your class as `@ApplicationScoped`. Make sure it has a public no-arg constructor and that this class doesn't have state and its methods are thread safe.

E.g.

Managed bean (pure JSF)

```
//this is important
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class Utility {
    public static String foo(String another) {
        return "hello " + another;
    }
}
```

CDI version

```
//this is important
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Utility {
    public static String foo(String another) {
        return "hello " + another;
    }
}
```

View

```
<h:outputText value="#{utility.foo('amphibient')}" />
```

Comment: ApplicationScoped. from `javax.enterprise.context` or `javax.faces.bean` ?  I tried both and I'm still not seeing it in the JSF, not showing in the drop down in JBoss Dev Studio

Comment: i can't find a way to actually give a name by which to call it in the JSF.  e.g. in a managed bean, it would be `@ManagedBean(name="myManagedBean")` and then to call `getFoo` in the JSF, I would do `myManagedBean.foo`.  how do I either refer to a non-nicknamed class or assign a JSF name to it ?

Comment: OK.  I didn't get the `@ManagedBean` part.

Comment: it works.  i used `javax.enterprise.context`.  we do use CDI and JSF, i didn't know the terms were mutually exclusive

Comment: one more question:  how does `@ApplicationScoped` make the bean different from other regular backing beans that are not annotated as that ?

Comment: The terms are not mutually exclusive, but the annotations are.

Comment: Answer updated to show the difference in annotations between JSF and CDI.