# Java - what's the difference between singleton and static-block-based classes initialization?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, singleton, static-block

Recently I learned Singleton pattern. And had to realize one. For example:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;

    private InnerObject innerObject; //all functionality is here

    private Singleton() {
        innerObject = new InnerObject();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public InnerObjectResult getResult() {
        return innerObject.getResult(); //delegate method call
    }
}
```

But earlier I would realize this one like this:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static InnerObject innerObject;

    static {
        innerObject = new InnerObject();
    }

    public static InnerObjectResult getResult() {
        return innerObject.getResult();
    }
}
```

Thus the result is the same: innerObject initialized once, but the code is cleaner and I don't have to worry about multithreading. I know that pattern doesn't rest on specific languages and probably you can't do something like this elsewhere, but I'm interested in this particular situation. Thank you very much!

Comment: That works just fine, but not all singletons are simple enough to be created that way.

Comment: What's the point of the singleton instance in your first example?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern

Comment: @horatius Thank you!