# Which is better to implement a singleton in a Spring application: a bean or a static field?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am developing Spring MVC app, i need to implement singleton pattern for some kind of utilities, ex: imageuploader and others.

My question is: in what way to implement singleton for this utilities, to **initialize beans** for these classes and inject where i need like Controllers, Services, DAO?, or to use **static field implementation of singleton** to keep instance of this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to avoid singleton as it's considered to be a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons). Also their interactions with other instances are difficult to test and validate, compared to non-singleton instances.

If you absolutely need it, I'd suggest you use a Spring bean so you can exploit the autowiring mechanism and Spring's bean lifecycle.

See the [*Beans*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) section of the Spring reference doc for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Spring bean as will allow you to easily inject a mock in unit tests. However, you will only be able to access it from other Spring beans (or objects created by Spring beans that pass in a reference to it).

Also see this discussion in this question: [Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

Traditionally, you'd use [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to inject config from properties files into a Spring web-app. [This blog](http://spring.io/blog/2015/01/13/configuring-it-all-out-or-12-factor-app-style-configuration-with-spring) discusses a variety of newer ways to do this with Spring.