# When to use singleton class over static class

Tags: c#, static, singleton

I have searched a lot difference between singleton and static class, Only I could convince myself is syntactical difference,on which I am not interested.

Could anyone tell me the real difference between static and singleton ?
When I should use only singleton not static or any other ?

Comment: You can see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

In short, Singleton *has* a (single) *instance*, while static class has *none*. So when you want to pass the instance, choose Singleton, e.g.:

```
  // EventArgs.Empty is a Singleton
  DoOnChange(myObject, EventArgs.Empty);
```

when you have *no need* in any instances use *static class*:

```
  public static class MyMath {
    public static Double GammaFunc(Double value) {...}
    ...
  }
```

Comment: But I can have a function in static class which serves the purpose of the object being passed. i.e if any outer class changes the value inside the function, will be impacted everywhere @ Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: @keerti_h: that's so called *side effect* which we usually should avoid for the reason you've named: "will be impacted everywhere" (or at least "elsewhere")