# Differentiate between logged users

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to get the current logged (in my app) user in every winform of my app, but I don't know how to differentiate between multiple logged users in the app.

I have an `ActiveUsers` SQL Table with `SessionID` and `UserID` to identify a single user.

Also how can I close the session (delete the `userid` from the `ActiveUsers` table) if the app is terminated abnormally?

Any help?

Edit: The app is composed of several winforms and is intended to run in multiple Pcs at the same time. Users are created in the application and stored in `SC_User` table with `UserID` as PK. The `ActiveUsers` table has `UserID` as FK and `SessionID` as PK. What i want is to get the `UserID` of the user using the applicattion in any winform and use it to for example change the app language preference of the that user. For a single user i insert the `UserID` in the `ActiveUsers` when login and delete when logoff.

Comment: your question is not clear. Are you saying you have ONE desktop application and each form in your app is using a different SQL USER?BTW, if you record user entrance and exit in your own table, I don't see any elegant way to handle abnormal termination. Please make your question more clear

Comment: You need to edit this question so that it makes more sense to someone who knows nothing about your application.

Comment: looks like you need use `SessionID` in the `ActiveUsers` table to track rather than `UserID`

Comment: Let's see if I understand correctly: Your application runs multiple copies on multiple computers, each by a different user. All users login to the application and that inserts a record to the ActiveUsers table with the user id and SessionId.  Now, your question is how to delete that record when the application is closed without proper logging out (i,e, a computer shut down because of power failure)? Or is your question how to keep the user id and session id in the application while the user opens a new form and closes the old one?

Comment: Thats right. The winform problem is the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping application-wide data is quite easy. All you have to do is add either a static ([shared](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx) in vb.net) class or a [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650849.aspx) class to your project and store the application-wide data there. (Extra read: [differences between singleton and static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern))

As for the second question, You don't really have a way to know if the client is closed without proper logout. What you do in these cases is implement a [keep-alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) mechanism.

A simple implementation would be to add another column to your session table to keep track off the time stamp when the logged in user was last active (usually a timer inside that static/singleton class will be in charge of updating this column every x time, and once the difference between this column and the current datetime is big enough, you can safely assume that the application is closed without proper logout.

You can even run a scheduled job on your sql server to delete the records on the session table where the application is closed without proper logout if you want to.