# How to show shadow or any glow effect for SKSpriteNode when it moved on screen only?

Tags: cocoa, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene, xamarin.mac

I want to show any effects or animations for my SKSpriteNode when it was dragging on screen.

I gone through many sites but i didn't find relevant answer for my question.I have little bit knowledge on SKSpriteNode.

Can any one guide me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using SKLightNodes?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40362874/6728196. It shows how to make a glowing effect. Then you can hide it when not moving or whatever you want

Comment: how are you currently creating your shadows?

Comment: or... how do you want your shadows to look and behave? Either answer will help me answer your question.

Comment: Okay i will explain... I have an Apple image on screen now i am able to drag that image using mouse.While i am dragging i need to show glow effect or shadow or something else.

Comment: Ok. So you want to show that it's been lifted up off the surface whilst being dragged? That's your reason for the glow/shadow? btw, when replying, add my name to the reply like I'll do with yours, here: @Mounika, that way I'll get notified of a reply.

Comment: @Confused Okay is there any way to solve my issue ?

Comment: just use SKLightNode, place it whereever you want your light source to come from

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I tried that here is my code                                                var  skLightNode = new SKLightNode(); 
skLightNode.LightColor = NSColor.White;
skLightNode.Position = new CGPoint(0, 0);
skLightNode.Falloff = 1;
skLightNode.AmbientColor = NSColor.DarkGray;       this.AddChild(skLightNode);                                                                                               but not showing any difference :(

Answer (score 3):

Use a factory to make a shadow:

```
import SpriteKit

class MAKE {

    private static let view:SKView = SKView()

    static func makeShadow(from source: SKTexture, rgb: SKColor, a: CGFloat) -> SKSpriteNode {
        let shadowNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: source)
            shadowNode.colorBlendFactor = 0.5  // makes the following line more effective
            shadowNode.color = SKColor.gray // makes for a darker shadow. Off for "glow" shadow
        let textureSize = source.size()
        let doubleTextureSize = CGSize(width: textureSize.width * 2, height: textureSize.height * 2)
        let framer = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.clear, size: doubleTextureSize)
            framer.addChild(shadowNode)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        let blurAmount = 10
        filter?.setValue(blurAmount, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        let effectsNode = SKEffectNode()
            effectsNode.filter = filter
            effectsNode.blendMode = .alpha
            effectsNode.addChild(framer)
            effectsNode.shouldRasterize = true
        let tex = view.texture(from: effectsNode)
        let shadow = SKSpriteNode(texture: tex)
            shadow.colorBlendFactor = 0.5
            shadow.color = rgb
            shadow.alpha = a
            shadow.zPosition = -1
    return shadow
    }
}
```

---

Now make a button anyway you like, but make sure you have created a `buttonTexture` that's the exact same size and shape as your button, preferably a grey rendition of it. You'll need this to send to the blurring factory shadowmaker above, like this:

```
shadowSprite = MAKE.makeShadow(from: buttonTexture, rgb: myColor, a: 0.33)
        shadowSprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY - 5)
        addChild(shadowSprite)
```

---

You can see more details on how and why a factory, here:
[Create \(Use) SKView as \(in a) factory \(static class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084701/create-use-skview-as-in-a-factory-static-class)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am trying in Xamarin.Mac i think its a swift code :(

Comment: I don't know anything about C# @Mounika. Or the key of E.

Comment: Hmm... okay i will try to your answer in tech

Comment: A majority of answers that you may find won't be in C#. Learning to translate to C# is an important skill. These docs may help - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/application_fundamentals/patterns/ https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/application_fundamentals/mac-apis/