# Best practices in two class

Tags: java, android, performance

if i need use a global class what is the best option and why?

```
public class Global {

    public static JSONObject GetJsonResquest(String url){
        ....
    };
}
```

and then call Global.GetJsonResquest(url) in my activity

**OR**

```
  public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton ourInstance = new Singleton();

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private Singleton() {
    }
    public JSONObject GetJsonResquest(String url){
      .....
    }
}
```

and then use via Singleton.getInstance().GetJsonResquest("Asd");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

Comment: But if i need use a constants variables... example TIME_DEFAULT = 4000 AND MORES... OR METHODS CalculateValue(int jjdsjd) what is the bes way? my question is for best practice when only need 1 function or 1 constant in the activity and dont need load all

Comment: in this code example isbetter case one, you dont need ANY instance of Global in order to convert the string into jsonObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need a global static variable, I like to group them into a class like

```
public class MyConstants {
    public static final int TIMEOUT = 10000;
}
```

To use it, i can call it like

```
long tick = System.currentThreadMillis();
while((System.currentThreadMillis() - tick) < MyConstants.TIMEOUT){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

So that when I change the TIMEOUT value, I don't have to change other classes that calls it

For global static method, I use them like

```
public class Utility{
     public static boolean isStringValidJson(String jsonString){
         return false;   
     }
}
```

Same reason as above. When I change *isStringValidJson*, other classes that calls it don't change

I do use the singleton pattern but only when I override the Application class. However, I set the instance value in *OnCreate* instead. This means that if *OnCreate* was not called, *getInstance* will return null

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
}
```