# c# difference between static member or static constructor and singleton

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Is there any difference /tradeoff between using a static **member object** and the singleton pattern?  I often use the code below in  C#,  but are there any use cases where the Singleton is preferred?

```
 public class MyStaticObject
    {
        static MyStaticObject _object =new MyStaticObject();

        // OR with static constructor
        //static MyStaticObject _object;
        //static MyStaticObject()
        //{
        //    _object = new MyStaticObject();
        //    // additional static construction logic...
        //    //   ...
        //}
    }
```

NOTE:  This is not the same question as:
[Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

and other questions which look at static CLASSES.  Here in my program, the `class` is not static, it is just a singleton object.  So I have all the benefits of inheritance as listed in the question in the link, but I am not using the singleton pattern for construction.

Comment: The singleton-pattern is usually combined with a readonly-instance which - once set - can´t be changed. With a static member you could change the instance. However there´s no difference in your code as both will go to a static constructor-call. You´re not using a singleton at all.

Comment: HImBromBeere: Hello, yes I realize I am not using a Singleton,  I am using the static constructor or static member in this case, with a singleton I would normally have a static method which checks if instance is null and then create and return it if it is null.  However I think I achieve the same result with a static constructor or static member.  So de we really need the singleton pattern then?

Comment: The point is as I already said you can change a static member as often as you want. A singleton however usually references the same instance during the whole lifetime of your app so you can *not* change that reference ( as it is `readonly`).

Answer (score 0):

Singleton pattern says that you will have only one instance of given type. You can achieve it in different ways. You can do it with static classes/members or using IoC container (which better from my point), or some another way.