# Save random array for use in entire app

Tags: java, arrays

I am very new in java.
I have a class that makes a random array with this code.

```
public class game {
    private int max = 32;
    private int min = 1;
    private Random r = new Random();
    private Integer[] words_Image = new Integer[10];
    public void setwords_Image(Integer[] words_Image) {
        this.words_Image = words_Image;
        for (int i = 0; i < words_Image.length; i++) {
            int num = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            int j = 0;
            while (j < i) {
                if (words_Image[j] == num) {
                    num = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
                    j = -1;
                }
                j += 1;
            }
            words_Image[i] = num;

        }

    }

    public Integer[] getWords_Image() {
        setwords_Image(words_Image);
        return words_Image;
    }
}
```

I want to make the array just once, then use the array in entire app while array remains constant.
I don't know how to do that because when I make an object from that class this array changed each time.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: you just need to know the role of `static` keyword in java. i hope my answer will help you.

Comment: What you really need is a singleton. @WasiAhmad’s suggestion, static variables, is one way to obtain an effective singleton. There are a couple of others, including an `enum`. Your favourite search engine should be great for finding the options — they surely are described in several places on the Net.

Comment: if my answer helped you, you can accept it. (saying this since you are new to stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1):

"because when i make an object from that class this array changed each time" - you need to know about the `static` keyword in java.

**Static Variables**: In Java, variables can be declared with the `static` keyword. An example is given below.

```
static int y = 0;
```

When a variable is declared with the keyword `static`, its called a class variable. All instances share the same copy of the variable. A class variable can be accessed directly with the class, without the need to create a instance.

Without the `static` keyword, it’s called instance variable, and each instance of the class has its own copy of the variable.

- It is a variable which belongs to the class and not to object(instance)
- Static variables are initialized only once , at the start of the execution. These variables will be initialized first, before the initialization of any instance variables.
- A single copy to be shared by all instances of the class.
- A static variable can be accessed directly by the class name and doesn’t need any object

Syntax : `<class-name>.<variable-name>`

Read the article on [Static Methods, Variables, Static Block and Class with Example](http://crunchify.com/java-static-methods-variables-static-block-and-class-with-example/) to know more in detail.

> Edit: I wanted you to explore and solve it of your own but since you are struggling, i am adding a solution. Note that, you can achieve what you want in many ways.

```
class Game {

    private static final int max = 32;
    private static final int min = 1;
    private static final Integer[] words_Image = new Integer[10];

    static {
        setwords_Image();
    }

    private static void setwords_Image() {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < words_Image.length; i++) {
            int num = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            int j = 0;
            while (j < i) {
                if (words_Image[j] == num) {
                    num = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
                    j = -1;
                }
                j += 1;
            }
            words_Image[i] = num;
        }
    }

    public Integer[] getWords_Image() {
        return words_Image;
    }
}

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game g1 = new Game();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g1.getWords_Image()));
        Game g2 = new Game();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g2.getWords_Image()));
    }
}
```

It outputs: (as you expect)

```
[1, 32, 18, 20, 27, 8, 9, 31, 3, 19]
[1, 32, 18, 20, 27, 8, 9, 31, 3, 19]
```

Comment: hi thank for answering. can you be more specific with my example?

Comment: i want words_image array that contain random numbers made one time then i can use that numbers in my app. when i make my variable static and use myclass.myvariable i get empty array at sratrt

Comment: I have updated my answer, hopefully it will help you. but i want to encourage you to go through the tutorial and learn everything about `static` in java :)

Answer (score 0):

What you really need is a singleton. This is a well known concept in programming, best known from the description in Gamma et al.: *Design Patterns*, popularly known as the Gang of Four book. You should take a look at the discussions in [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java). The two top answers both advocate an `enum` for implementing the singleton in Java, while other options are also mentioned in the answers. In your case an `enum` may look like this:

```
public enum Game {
    INSTANCE;

    private int max = 32;
    private int min = 1;
    private int size = 10;
    private final int[] wordsImage;

    private Game() {
        wordsImage = new int[size];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < wordsImage.length; i++) {
            int num = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
            int j = 0;
            while (j < i) {
                if (wordsImage[j] == num) {
                    num = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
                    j = -1;
                }
                j += 1;
            }
            wordsImage[i] = num;
        }
    }

    public int[] getWordsImage() {
        return wordsImage;
    }
}
```

Classes that need to access the random array do for instance:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Game.INSTANCE.getWordsImage()));
```

If you want to prevent code that uses the array from putting other numbers in it, return only a copy to callers:

```
    return Arrays.copyOf(wordsImage, size);
```

Comment: If you think that there is any need to make a singleton and that a static variable doesn't suffice, please justify your answer.

Comment: Each option — static variables and other implementations of singleton — has its pros and cons. You may read more here: [Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

Comment: I know the difference and in the case of an array of integers, I don't see any pros in making a singleton. Only cons. So, if you believe that a singleton is better in this particular case, please justify your answer.

Comment: I am not saying one is better than the other in this particular case. I wanted to present the different options, and I am happy to trust the asker to make the pick that suits him or her best. @Sharcoux