# Laravel controller static var always null

Tags: laravel, variables, static

I was trying to declare a static var, but always is null, I try several combinations and ways without luck. I'm trying to store a var with some data, but I really don't want to reprocess, If already was processed one time.

```
            class PackingController extends Controller
            {
                protected static $i;

                function Process(Request $request)
                {
                    $r = new packing();
                    $v = $r->customer('data','data');
                    $items = $this->startProcess($v,false);
                    return \View::make('list/print',compact('items'));

                }

                private function startProcess($dbitems, $ajust=false)
                {

                //Some logic

                self::$i = $items;
                return $items;

                }

                function printPdf()
                {

                    $items = self::$i;
                    //shows null:
                    dd($items);
                }
            }
```

What's is wrong?

Update: I try with singleton without luck.

```
        namespace App\Helper;

        class Items
        {

            private static $_items;
            private static $inst;

            public function setItems($value)
            {
                self::$_items = $value;
            }

            public function getItems()
            {
                return self::$_items;
            }


            public static function Instance()
            {
                if (self::$inst == null) {
                    self::$inst = new Items();
                }

                return self::$inst;
            }

            private function __clone()
            {
            }

            private function __construct()
            {
            }

        }
```

With singleton, still null, Also try with a single value, instead of variable, without luck

```
    class PackingController extends Controller
    {
        protected static $i;


        function GetPackings()
        {
            $s = sales::with('Customer')->where('salestype','=','3')->take(1000)->orderBy('receiptdaterequested','desc')->pluck('salesid','salesid');

            $p = pack::distinct('APPACKINGGROUPID')->pluck('APPACKINGGROUPID','APPACKINGGROUPID')->all();

            return \View::make('listas/index',compact('p','s'));
        }

        function Process(Request $request)
        {
            $r = new packing();
            $v = $r->customer('Mexico','PVE0111998');
            $items = $this->startProcess($v,false);
            return \View::make('listas/print',compact('items'));

        }

        private function startProcess($dbitems, $ajust=false)
        {
            $bultos = 1;

            $items = array();

            foreach ($dbitems as $dbitem)
            {
            //Some process

                $items[]=$item;
            }

            $s = Items::Instance();

            if (count($items) > 0 ) {
                $s->setItems($items);
            }

            return $items;
        }

        function printPdf()
        {
            $s = Items::Instance();
            $s->getItems();

            dd($s->getItems());
        }
    }
```

Comment: self::$i = $items where is $items defined or is it $dbitems?

Comment: $items are the result of $dbitems process, is one array, I try with singleton without luck, I really don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you tryings to declare a static var or *singleton* to pass values between the [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern?rq=1)? 
Maybe you should try with save data in session:

```
session()->set('items',$dbtitems);
```

And...

```
$items = session()->get('items);
```

Comment: I try that, but still null,

Comment: session()->put('items',$items);
session()->save();
$items = session()->get('items');