# Is a public static DateTime field an anti pattern or a good practice?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In our program we have so called `WallclockDateTime`. Because we can shift in time, this `WallclockDateTime` is not related to the current time. But now I need this `WallclockDateTime` everywhere in my classes.

First I decided to pass this `WallclockDateTime` by reference from constructor to constructor. But that takes a lot of maintenance. And now I have some class `Foo` which is created in masses in a `Collection<Foo>`, and passing this same `WallClockTime` over and over again through the constructor seemed a bit useless to me. So I thought: Can't this be done more efficient?

First I tried to make the central `WallclockDateTime` static. **EDIT:** But I'm not allowed to use `OnPropertyChanged()` inside a static property and it is from outside my solution.
If I make `_wallclockDateTime` public and static I can get to it everywhere! But it seems dirty to me. So what is a good solution for this? Passing from constructor to constructor? Or make the field public and static? Or some other clever solution?

```
    private DateTime _wallclockDateTime;
    public DateTime WallclockDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return _wallclockDateTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_wallclockDateTime != value)
            {
                _wallclockDateTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WallclockDateTime));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentSliderStateLabel));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WallclockDateTimeTicks));
            }
        }
    }

// This class is used in a Collection<Foo>
public class Foo
{
    private static DateTime _wallClockTime;

    public Foo(ref DateTime wallClockTime)
    {
        _wallClockTime = wallClockTime;
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        // Do something with the _wallClockTime
    }
}
```

Comment: could you not just define _wallClockTime in a base class?

Comment: @Rango I do know static. I need ONE instance of a WallClockDateTime, but I need to see it everywhere.

Comment: @ffonz So you want a `public static` field... You *could* use a Singleton, but that's basically as dirty as a `public static` field

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If I don't use `ref` I get all different times, since DateTime is a primitive type and not an object.

Comment: @ffonz: you can make the property `public static`, the backing field should not be public. I'd wrap the setter in a `lock`-statement

Comment: @Rango But I'm not allowed to use  `OnNotifyPropertyChanged()` inside a static property.

Comment: You may want to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto my thoughts exactly. Singleton seems to be the most reasonable choice here.

Comment: @ffonz: So you can't make the property-changed event `static` because it's not part of your solution? Otherwise you can use: `public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler WallclockDateTimeChanged;

  private static void OnWallclockDateTimeChanged(string name = null)
  {
   WallclockDateTimeChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }`

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to use Dependency Injection. You create a service provider and a service that supports all of your date needs.

Microsoft has a dependency injection system, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

You can either have the service put into the constructors of other services, or else just access it directly.

There is a view that says that dependency injection is just a fancy way to have global variables. On the other hand, when used with interface definitions for each service in a large system it probably does improve the ability to test components.

One other comment, in most cases DateTimeOffset is better than DateTime, because it eliminates the ambiguity of what time zone the date/time is relative to.