# Could someone explain to me how this singleton pattern works?

Tags: python, singleton

I'm using this Singleton pattern and it works, but I can't figure out what it is doing. Could someone explain to me how this program works?

Thanks!

```
class Singleton(object):
  _instances = {}
  def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
    if class_ not in class_._instances:
        class_._instances[class_] = super(Singleton, class_).__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
    return class_._instances[class_]

class Context(Singleton):
    #do things
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with? Do you understand what `__new__` is? Do you understand what `super` is? Do you understand what a dict is and how it works?

Comment: @khelwood As far as I know, __new__ is going to be called when a Singleton object is created, and super is refering to the parent class __new__ method. (Am I right?)

I think I'm gettin lost in inheritance flow. For example, what will be the parent class of Singleton class? object? What is object exactly?

Answer (score 1):

`__new__` is called when you try and instantiate a particular class.

When you try and instantiate a Context, it uses the `__new__` method defined in Singleton. This method first looks to see if the class (Context) has an entry in Singleton's `_instances` dictionary.

- If it *hasn't*, then a new instance is created using `super(Singleton, class_).__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)`. This is calling the `__new__` method in `object`: the default `__new__` method that normally creates new instances. It gets a new instance of Context from that, and stores it in the `_instances` dictionary, linked to the Context class, so it can look it up next time.
- If it *has*, then the Context class has already been instantiated, so we can get the instance from the dictionary and return it.

Comment: Thanks. I can see It much clearer now. There is one thing that confuses me. Why it uses Its parent's __new__ method (which I understand the parent is "object", which is the root class they all inherit from in python, right?)

Comment: The superclass's `__new__` method is what Singleton's `__new__` method is overriding. If it wants the instantiation to go ahead, it falls back on the default behaviour, which is the thing it overrode, to create the instance.

Answer (score 1):

The singleton pattern refers to a class that you can only initiate once. If you try to create a second object of a singleton class, it will just return the already initiated object

Let's analyze the code a little step by step

```
_instances = {}
```

This is a dictionary where we save the objects we have already created. An important thing to understand here is that this is shared among the objects. When you create a new object you always get the same dictionary.

```
if class_ not in class_._instances:
    class_._instances[class_] = super(Singleton, class_).__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now as I mentioned before, singleton creates an object once and it returns it again if you try to create a new object. This code here checks if we have already created the object by looking inside of the dictionary. If we haven't created it it will create a new object and it will save it to the _instances dictionary. If it already exists it will just skip this code.

```
return class_._instances[class_]
```

We then return the object that it is guaranteed to be there. Remember that we have already checked that we haven't created an instance of this class so we can create a new one. If it was already created, we just return it from the dictionary.